# How to generate separate bounding boxes for non-contiguous photo color mask areas

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I want to generate bounding boxes for approximately non-contiguous areas of a photo by color mask--in this case, green bands containing vegetation--so that I can clip that area to pass to an image classification function.

This is something that can be done with geospatial rasters fairly easily using GDAL, to polygonize areas of geotiff that have similar characteristics (https://www.gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html). But in this case, I am trying to do this to a photo. I haven't found a solution for pure rasters.

For example, take a photo like this one:

[image]

which is masked into green bands using openCV and numpy:

```
 try:
            hsv=cv.cvtColor(image,cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        except:
            print("File may be corrupt")
            return(0,0)
        # Define lower and uppper limits of what we call "brown"
        brown_lo=np.array([18,0,0])
        brown_hi=np.array([28,255,255])

        green_lo=np.array([29,0,0])
        green_hi=np.array([88,255,255])

        # Mask image to only select browns
        mask_brown=cv.inRange(hsv,brown_lo,brown_hi)
        mask_green=cv.inRange(hsv,green_lo,green_hi)


        hsv[mask_brown>0]=(18,255,255)
        hsv[mask_green>0]=(53,255,255)

        image2=cv.cvtColor(hsv,cv.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
        cv.imwrite(QUERIES + 'queries/mask.jpg', image2)
```

[image]

I'd like to generate boxing boxes or polygons for the areas indicated here:

[image]

Any ideas how to do that?

I tried using openCV contours and convexhull algorithms, but they don't really get me anywhere:

[image]

```
 threshold = val
    # Detect edges using Canny
    canny_output = cv.Canny(src_gray, threshold, threshold * 2)
    # Find contours
    _, contours, _ = cv.findContours(canny_output, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    # Find the convex hull object for each contour
    hull_list = []
    for i in range(len(contours)):
        hull = cv.convexHull(contours[i])
        hull_list.append(hull)
    # Draw contours + hull results
    drawing = np.zeros((canny_output.shape[0], canny_output.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    for i in range(len(contours)):
        color = (rng.randint(0,256), rng.randint(0,256), rng.randint(0,256))
        cv.drawContours(drawing, contours, i, color)
        cv.drawContours(drawing, hull_list, i, color)
    # Show in a window
    cv.imshow('Contours', drawing)
```

Comment: Well, you can either find the _points/coordinates_ where the image has a specific color using [contours](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html)  and then use [convex hull](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d1d/tutorial_hull.html) OR you can work with HSV color space you have and basically just find regions which fall into a range of intensities (either in the entire color space or one of the channels) as you have done here. May be [this link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d0c/tutorial_bounding_rects_circles.html) puts you in the correct direction.

Comment: @RickM.Thank you, that looks like it is the solution. I'll post back with the answer if I can get it to work. Thank you!

Comment: I updated the ticket with my attempts to use openCV convexhill, which did not work. I am wondering if I need to try semantic image segmentation.

Comment: Ok, let me give it a try. I will get back to you by the end of the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as you tried with contours and it didn't work, I tried to go the clustering way. I started off with K-means which is the best place to start IMO. Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans, MeanShift
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def centroid_histogram(clt):
    numlabels = np.arange(0, len(np.unique(clt.labels_)) + 1)
    (hist, _) = np.histogram(clt.labels_, bins=numlabels)

    hist = hist.astype("float")
    hist /= hist.sum()

    return hist


def plot_colors(hist, centroids):
    bar = np.zeros((50, 300, 3), dtype="uint8")
    startX = 0

    for (percent, color) in zip(hist, centroids):
        endX = startX + (percent * 300)
        cv2.rectangle(bar, (int(startX), 0), (int(endX), 50),
                      color.astype("uint8").tolist(), -1)
        startX = endX

    return bar

image1 = cv2.imread('mean_shift.jpg')
image1 = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
image = image1.reshape((image1.shape[0] * image1.shape[1], 3))

#clt = MeanShift(bandwidth=2, bin_seeding=True)
clt = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
clt.fit(image)

hist = centroid_histogram(clt)
bar = plot_colors(hist, clt.cluster_centers_)
plt.figure()
plt.axis("off")
plt.imshow(bar)
plt.show()
```

Using 3 cluster centers, I got the following result:

[image: Cluster Probability]

and using 6 cluster centers:

[image: Cluster Probability 6]

which basically shows you the proportion of these colors in the image.

The links that helped me do this:

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/05/26/opencv-python-k-means-color-clustering/ and

https://github.com/log0/build-your-own-meanshift/blob/master/Meanshift%20Image%20Segmentation.ipynb

Now, there are couple of issues I see here:

1. You might not know the number of clusters in all the images. In that case, you should look into [Mean-Shift](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_mean_shift.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-mean-shift-py). Unlike the K-Means algorithm, meanshift does not require specifying the number of clusters in advance. The number of clusters is determined by the algorithm with respect to the data.
2. I have used [SLIC](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_segmentations.html) in these kind of problems. It is a subset of the K-means-based algorithms and is very efficient. You can also give this one a try since it is available in [scikit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html), which is the goto library for machine learning in python IMO. In the same direction, you could also give [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/03/semantic-segmentation-with-opencv-and-deep-learning/) a try.

Hope I have helped you some way! Cheers!

Comment: I am in awe of your generous help, thank you! Lots of great ideas to follow up on.

Comment: Great! Glad that I could help :)